# How can I group a sorted list into tuples of start and endpoints of consecutive elements of this list?

Tags: python

Suppose that my sorted list is as such:

```
L = ["01-string","02-string","03-string","05-string","07-string","08-string"]
```

As you can see this list has been sorted. I now want the start and end points of each block of continuous strings in this list, for example, the output for this should be:

```
L_continuous = [("01-string", "03-string"),("05-string","05-string"),("07-string","08-string")]
```

So, just to clarify, I need a list of tuples and in each of these tuples I need the start and endpoint of each consecutive block in my list. So, for example, elements 0, 1 and 2 in my list are consecutive because 01,02,03 are consecutive numbers - so the start and endpoints would be "01-string" and "03-string".

The numbers 1-3 are consecutive so they form a block, whereas 5 does not have any consecutive numbers in the list so it forms a block by itself.

Comment: So... How do you want them grouped again? It isn't apparent by your expected output

Comment: @Jab A list of tuples that have the start and endpoint of each consecutive block

Comment: So where did `"02-string"` go? And how is `"05-string"` a block? How are you defining "blocks"?

Comment: I should think it's straightforward that the numbers 1-3 are consecutive so they form a block, whereas 5 does not have any consecutive numbers in the list so it forms a block by itself.

Comment: @kaya3 I don't think that was evident from the question itself, but I agree with your interpretation.  Though I'd still argue the behaviour for the `05`s is still not apparent.

Comment: "02-string" is in between the consecutive block "01-string","02-string","03-string", so the start point is "01-string" and the endpoint is "03-string". However, "05-string" is both an endpoint and a start point because the elements before and after arent "04-string" and "06-string" respectively

Comment: @kaya3 's interpretation of the question is correct. I am not sure what else a consecutive block could mean. Forgive me if there is any ambiguity in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing to do is extract an int from the string data, so that we can compare consecutive *numbers*:

```py
def extract_int(s):
    return int(s.split('-')[0])
```

Then a straightforward solution is to keep track of the last number seen, and emit a new block when it is not consecutive with the previous one. At the end of the loop, we need to emit a block of whatever is "left over".

```py
def group_by_blocks(strs):
    blocks = []
    last_s = first_s = strs[0]
    last_i = extract_int(last_s)

    for s in strs[1:]:
        i = extract_int(s)
        if i != last_i + 1:
            blocks.append( (first_s, last_s) )
            first_i, first_s = i, s
        last_i, last_s = i, s

    blocks.append( (first_s, last_s) )
    return blocks
```

Example:

```py
>>> group_by_blocks(L)
[('01-string', '03-string'), ('05-string', '05-string'), ('07-string', '08-string')]
```

Answer (score 1):

Not a one-liner, but something like this might work:

```
L = ["01-string","02-string","03-string","05-string","07-string","08-string"]
counter = None
# lastNum = None
firstString = ""
lastString = ""
L_continuous = list()
for item in L:
    currentNum = int(item[0:2])
    if counter is None:
        # startTuple
        firstString = item
        counter = currentNum
        lastString = item
        continue
    if counter + 1 == currentNum:
        # continuation of block
        lastString = item
        counter += 1
        continue
    if currentNum > counter + 1:
        # end of block
        L_continuous.append((firstString,lastString))
        firstString = item
        counter = currentNum
        lastString = item
        continue
    else:
        print ('error - not sorted or unique numbers')
# add last block
L_continuous.append((firstString,lastString))

print(L_continuous)
```